# cv fails to locate civicrm.settings.php

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, cv

I have an error on CivicCRM v 5.11 "Cron Not Running" (WordPress)

The crontab entry reads

> */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/cv api --user=www-data job.execute

The cron job fails with:

> [Exception]   Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php.

so I told bash

> CIVICRM_SETTINGS="/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"

this file is owned by linux user www-data, same as who owns apache

variable assignment echoes back correctly, e.g.:

> echo $CIVICRM_SETTINGS
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

and so I run cv by hand like this:

> cv api -vvv Job.execute

and get the same error about not knowing where civicrm.settings.php lives:

> Attempting to set verbose error reporting [BaseCommand::boot] Start
>   [BaseCommand::boot] Call standard cv bootstrap [Bootstrap] Options: {
>       "dynamicSettingsFile": "phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/settings_location.php",
>       "env": "CIVICRM_SETTINGS",
>       "prefetch": true,
>       "settingsFile": null,
>       "search": true,
>       "cmsType": null,
>       "httpHost": "",
>       "output": {} } [Bootstrap] Find settings file
>
> [Exception]   Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default,
>   this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal,
>   WordPress,    etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and
>   multisite configurations may interfere. To customize, set variable
>   CIVICRM_S   ETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.
>
> Exception trace:  () at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Bootstrap.php:147
>   Civi\Cv\Bootstrap->boot() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/BaseCommand.php:62 
>   Civi\Cv\Command\BaseCommand->boot() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/ApiCommand.php:48 
>   Civi\Cv\Command\ApiCommand->execute() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:257
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:850 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:124 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Application.php:17 
>   Civi\Cv\Application::main() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/bin/cv:22 
>   require() at /usr/local/bin/cv:10
>
> api [--in IN] [--out OUT] [--level LEVEL] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]
>   [--]  []...

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: When you set CIVICRM_SETTINGS try prefixing the word export, otherwise child processes don't inherit it. i.e. export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=...

Comment: Thanks much for this - and it led to the solution.

The solution was a) to chown the  /civicrm root to www-data, which had changed to root due to an upgrade and b) give write access to www-data to the /civicrm/templates_c

THANKS MUCH for pointing out that bit of bash usage.  Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm still confused.  While Civi dashboard no longer complains about cron, I'm still getting sysadmin mail indicating :

  Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configurations may interfere. To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.

Comment: Whose crontab is it? Does the crontab belong to a user that doesn't have write access? If that's not it, try wrapping the crontab command in a little script that sets the variable first, then call that script instead from cron.

Comment: With the crontab entry being 

*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/cv api --user=www-data job.execute

this means the user running the job is www-data, no?

Comment: No they're separate. And that's another point too: --user in the cv call refers to the CMS user.